# Webpage changes size when I click to a new page

Tags: html, css, web, styles

I am fairly new to HTML and CSS, so bear with me...

I am trying to link different pages on my main webpage, and whenever I change pages the whole new page gets reformatted.

Anyone know what could be the problem with it?

I used a sticky footer code snippet from online, and it seems to come from that. I used a page to warp up the whole page and make the footer stick to the bottom.

```
* {
margin: 0;
}
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    /* equal to footer height */
    margin-bottom: -40px; 
}
.page-wrap:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
}
.main-footer, .page-wrap:after {
     height: 40px; 
}
.main-footer {
    background: orange;
}
```

Comment: Please add url/link of demo where we can see the issue.

Comment: i can't seem to add any photos, but I took out the sticky footer and I'm just linking a page using images and it is reformatted the whole page. the height and width changes when i change pages.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is just with the position of the body of your html.
Try to fix its position as well

```
body{
    position:fixed;
    }
```

for fixing the footer at the bottom use given code and remove the css for  .main-footer, .page-wrap:after and .page-wrap:after

```
body{
 position:fixed;
}
.page-wrap {
min-height: 100%;
}
.main-footer {
background: orange;
position:fixed;
}
```

also give parent div with bootstrap class inside your html as

```
<html>
<body>    
<div class="container">
 ....
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still didn't work.. I took out that piece of code. Now it seems to be just when i change pages. the height and width of the body changes as i switch pages through my links.